# Connecting android application to MySQL on VPS server [Amazon EC2]

Tags: android, mysql, amazon-ec2, vps

I try to develop android application that connects to mysql database on vps server (amazon ec2) and I searched many times without getting any way for that.
I will be grateful if anyone can help.
Thanks

Comment: At least read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15853367/jdbc-vs-web-service-for-android

Comment: You should not connect directly to MySQL from your app.  To do so requires embedding MySQL credentials into your app and it should be readily apparent why this is a bad idea.  You need to develop an intermediate API so that your app can talk to the database through intermediate logic over HTTPS.